# Runtime Error '459': Object or class does not support the set of events

Tags: excel, vba, class, runtime-error, activex

i have created a simple class named **Class1** and was testing if events are available for the objects or containers listed with WithEvents.

[image: Class1]

**Class1**:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents Obj As OLEObject

Private Sub Obj_GotFocus()
    MsgBox "Got U"
End Sub

Private Sub Obj_LostFocus()
    MsgBox "Lost U"
End Sub
```

As i understand, **OleObject** is a **container** and such it has the above 2 events listed for it.

In **Module1**, this is a simple code which sets a single OleObject on **Sheet1** of my workbook. For testing purpose, I have added **5 different ActiveX controls** to see which one gets the events.

**Module1**:

```
Option Explicit

Dim clsObj As Class1

Sub doit()
    Set clsObj = New Class1
    Set clsObj.Obj = Sheet1.OLEObjects(1) ' Getting error 459 on this line
End Sub
```

The following line above results in an error:

> Runtime Error '459':
>   Object or class does not support the set of events

**Note**:

> I can add a WithEvents to the object within this container e.g.
>   a **Label1** and get it to work, but it gives a different set of
>   events and not the Got_Focus() & Lost_Focus() events. However, this is not what i want :

**Class1**:

[image: MSForms.Label]

**Module1**:

[image: Module1]

**Questions**:

1. Can anyone explain why code does not allow to set the OleObject
   container object?
2. What is the logic or purpose behind making these events available
   when they cannot be triggered at all?
3. Why is the error message informing that these events are not
   available for any of the ActiveX controls added to Sheet1?
4. Is there an alternative way to access the 2 OleObject container
   events?

Comment: 4: Add Object to sheet, go to your sheet in the VBA Project Explorer, in the left Dropdown list above the code-window you can choose the OLE Object and in the Right Dropdown list you can select the Events.

Comment: @horst that is already added. See the error I am getting. I hope you read my entire post.  :)

Comment: Try Sheet1.OLEObjects(1).Object

Comment: @hans Prashant, you are setting an object to a container I. E. Oleobject. It doesn't work that way.